In Google Sheets, how can I apply conditional formatting to data that is being moved from one sheet to another via an onEdit Script?
I am building out a sheet to track tasks against a deadline and have created conditional formatting to highlight the deadline date based on how many days remain until the deadline (0-7 days = red, 7-14 = yellow, 14+ = green).
Within the sheet I also have two checkbox columns: "Assigned" and "Completed".
I have utilized an onEdit script to move the row to a new sheet when assigned and another sheet when completed. The conditional formatting is applied to all three sheets however, when the data moves to the new sheets it is no longer retains the conditional formatting.
I am pretty new to all this and can't seem to figure out how to make the conditional formatting apply to the data that is being moved over.
I am using an onEdit Script based off the tutorials from Spencer Farris. The script is below:
function moveAssigned(src, r) {
  if (r.rowStart == 1 || r.columnStart != 6) return;
  let dest;
  if (src.getName() == "Intake")
    dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Assigned");
  else if (src.getName() == "Assigned")
    dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Intake");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart, 1, 1, 7).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 7));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
}

function moveCompleted(src, r) {
  if (r.rowStart == 1 || r.columnStart != 7) return;
  let dest;
  if (src.getName() == "Intake")
    dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Completed");
  else if (src.getName() == "Assigned")
    dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Completed");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart, 1, 1, 7).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 7));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
}

I have applied conditional formatting to all three sheets (Input, Assigned, and Completed) but when the data is moved via the script from Input to one of the other sheets the conditional formatting breaks.

What is a conditional formatting breaks?
